# Characters count in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have the following textarea:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TxtBox200" runat="server" 
        TextMode="MultiLine" MaxLength="200" ></asp:TextBox>
<span id="charCount"></span>
```

why isn't the following javascript working:

```
<script>
    $('#TxtBox200').keypress(function() {
    var max = 200;
    var textLen = $(this).val().length;
    var textLeft = max - textLen;
    $('#charCount').text(
        textLeft + ' character' + (textLeft == 1 ? '' : 's') + ' left'
    );
});
</script>
```

EDIT: any ideas how I can cater for backsapce (thus no of characters left increase)?

Answer (score 4):

If you're using C# 4+ you'll probably need to use `ClientIDMode = Static` to make that work, otherwise your id will be changed by asp.net render engine and won't be `TxtBox200`

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TxtBox200" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"
    TextMode="MultiLine" MaxLength="200" >
```

If you're using C# < 4 and your javascript code is inline use @Sean Bright answer. If it's on a separated js file, you'll need to pass the id as parameter or use a css class as selector.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TxtBox200" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"
    TextMode="MultiLine" MaxLength="200" CssClass="TxtBox200" >
```

and your selector would be

```
$('input.TxtBox200').keypress(function() {...}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because in the generated HTML, `TxtBox200` is not actually called `TxtBox200`.  Try this instead:

```
$('<%= TxtBox200.ClientID %>').keypress(function() {
```

Comment: It's been a few years since I have done ASP.NET development and I wasn't aware of `ClientIDMode`.  That may be a better solution.  [See @Claudio's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17746030/21926).

Answer (score 1):

try including your javascript code in the window.load event

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function (e) {
    $('#TxtBox200').keypress(function() {
    var max = 200;
    var textLen = $(this).val().length;
    var textLeft = max - textLen;
    $('#charCount').text(
        textLeft + ' character' + (textLeft == 1 ? '' : 's') + ' left'
    );
});
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks this solved half my problem, the other half was to add ClientIDMode to static like Claudio suggested

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure you ID is the same for the text box on the client side since asp.net can change it. Make the ClientID Mode Static (http://www.devcurry.com/2009/08/clientid-mode-in-aspnet-40.html) or do something like:

```
$('[id$=TxtBox200]').keypress(function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

So there are 2 problems:

First, your jQuery keypress function is not within the DOM ready event, so it is trying to bind to your textbox before it is available, so instead write your script like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#<%= TxtBox200.ClientID %>').keypress(function(e) {
            alert('Key pressed.');
            var max = 200;
            var textLen = $(this).val().length;
            var textLeft = max - textLen;
            $('#charCount').text(
                textLeft + ' character' + (textLeft == 1 ? '' : 's') + ' left'
            );
        });
    });
```

Secondly, you need to reference your ASP.NET server control differently in your jQuery selector, because ASP.NET applies a hierarchical naming convention by default (i.e. MainContent_ctl100). You can force an ASP.NET server control to have a client name be static, like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TxtBox200" runat="server" 
             TextMode="MultiLine" MaxLength="200" ClientIDMode="Static" ></asp:TextBox>
```

This will make the `TextBox`'s ID be `TxtBox200` and thus be referenced by `.ClientID` in the jQuery selector.